# Using window.getComputedStyle for pseuso elements style with css calc

Tags: javascript, css

I've got some elements on the page that have a before pseudo element whose height is styled with the CSS calc() function; something like this:

```
.el:before: {
    content: "";
    height: calc(50% + 10px);
}
```

I want to use [this method](https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element) to get the height of the `:before` element - and in Webkit-based browsers it works and returns a pixel value.

```
var height = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.el'), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('height');
```

In Firefox, however, it returns the actual string of the CSS rule (exactly `'calc(50% + 10px)'`).

```js
(function() {
  var height = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('.myelem'), ':before'
  ).getPropertyValue('height');
  
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Calculated height is: ' + height;
})();
```

```css
.myelem {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.myelem:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(50% + 2px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myelem">
    <span>Some stuff here</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed a bug,

For a fix, you can vote for this [bug-report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694) from 2013 and hope that it will finally get fixed, or even propose a patch if you've got some time and C++ knowledge ;-)

For a workaround, you'll have to compute it yourself...

Comment: PS : for the workaround, e.generalov does provide something in the [comments of the bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694#c7) that seems to work : http://jsfiddle.net/3FecG/3/

Comment: Also, [looks like it got fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694#c24)